# using flags to go different web view in ios objective c

Tags: ios

I created three menu button which is home,login and setting.In home menu, I showed home web page using web view that it has web page menu links.

In login menu, if I pressed login button after filled username and password, I would like to go login web page of home web page link which need to appear under of home button.

I used flags.If flag is true,go to login web page and false is to go home web page.

But, it isn't work.

I would like to know which method can I use.

In iOS, I am beginner so I don't know which method is good to use.

**In viewcontroller.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (flag) {
       //I created home web view that webview is ok
    } else {
       //login web view if flag is true
    }
  }

- (IBAction)loginAction:(id)sender {
    BOOL flag=YES;
}
```

Comment: Everybody is a beginner sometime, don't worry about that. But you should post some code to show what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow either of these two process:

**Process 1:**

You can use global `bool` variable in `app delegate` class.

Add this code in `appdelegate.h`

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL ISLogin;
```

and add this code in appdelegate.m

```
@synthesize ISLogin;
```

whenever you can check using this

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)([[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]); 

if (appDelegate.ISLogin==Yes)
{
//you have to load the home url 
}
else
{
// you have to load the login url.
}
```

**Process 2**

Use `NSUserDefaults`. when login button tab you can add this code:

```
 NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 [defaults setObject:@"1" forKey:@"LogIn"];
 [defaults synchronize];
```

and you can check using this code.

```
NSString *key=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"LogIn"];

if ([key isEqualToString:@"1"])
{
//you have to load the home weburl
}
else
{
//you can load the login url
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to share the flag between Home and Login page, I guess you want to load data about the login user with the login user's info?

For share data between two ViewController, you can use singleton instance
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

or use NSUserDefaults, when user login, set the value to local, and go to Home page, read the value and refresh the webview.